# Written like this, using "as", will it be understood that...?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning

> Mike slips around a corner in the hallway just **as** two police officers enter from the stairwell.

Written like this, using "as", will it be understood that Mike makes it around the corner without being seen by the two police officers?

I know that using "before" could make it more clear, but I want it to mean that he slips around the corner the second they enter.

Comment: It's clear to me... *just* also helps there

Answer (score 2):

[**as**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as) in this context means "during the time that"".

It does not make it *clear* that Mike is not seen by the police, but it introduces the possibility, and subsequent dialog will confirm what actually happened.